# How to do pattern matching on mulit line string?

Tags: regex, android, pattern-matching

```
mystring = "
<div class="text">
    Spor
    </div>
";

pattern ="<div class=\"text\">(.*)</div>";
Pattern regEx = Pattern.compile(pattern, Pattern.MULTILINE);

Matcher m = regEx.matcher(myString);
if (m.find()) {
    match = m.group(1);
} else {
 match = "---";
}
```

not working ?

Comment: No way to understand what you want to do without any explanation. Just a snippet of code _does_ work as it should. If it isn't what you want is another thema...

Answer (score 1):

The 'dot' character doesn't include line break characters by default.
You have to enable it with `Pattern.DOTALL`.